# How do I fix a deep if-else nested

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm having trouble thinking of a way to reduce my `if else` nesting. It looks really wrong to me and there must be a better way to do this. Please kindly show me how.

```
if pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.gilt.rawValue ||
    pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.offDutySow.rawValue ||
    pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.matingSow.rawValue ||
    pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.drySow.rawValue ||
    pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.farrow.rawValue {
    if parityTextField.text != "" {
        pigData["parity"] = parityTextField.text!
    } else if pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.gilt.rawValue {
        if arrivalDateTextField.text != "" {
            pigData["arrivalDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: arrivalDateTextField.text!)
            pigData["herdEntryDate"] = (herdEntryDateTextField.text != "") ? Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: herdEntryDateTextField.text!) : ""
        }
    } else if pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.offDutySow.rawValue {
        if arrivalDateTextField.text != "" &&
            herdEntryDateTextField.text != "" &&
            startOffDutySowDateTextField.text != "" {
            pigData["arrivalDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: arrivalDateTextField.text!)
            pigData["herdEntryDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: herdEntryDateTextField.text!)
            pigData["startOffDutySowDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: startOffDutySowDateTextField.text!)
        }
    } else if pigTypeTextField.text == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.matingSow.rawValue {
        if arrivalDateTextField.text != "" &&
            herdEntryDateTextField.text != "" &&
            startOffDutySowDateTextField.text != "" &&
            semenFromBoarIDTextField.text != "" &&
            technicianNameTextField.text != "" &&
            matingDateTextField.text != "" {
            pigData["arrivalDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: arrivalDateTextField.text!)
            pigData["herdEntryDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: herdEntryDateTextField.text!)
            pigData["startOffDutySowDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: startOffDutySowDateTextField.text!)
            pigData["semenFromBoarID"] = semenFromBoarIDTextField.text!
            pigData["technicianName"] = technicianNameTextField.text!
            pigData["matingDate"] = matingDateTextField.text!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a task for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how many different pig types are there?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but today (go figure) I saw this post from Sunday: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/early-returning-functions-in-swift There's a lot more on his site that may help you. EDIT: While I agree that your code may need a bit of "fixing", 2 levels of `if` or 'if else`` really isn't too bad. What I think you are trying to do is achieve "readable" or "self-documenting" code.

Comment: @dfd well those are just a part of my nested if-else. The ì-else doesnt bug me what bug me is the repeated dictionary assign stuff in each if else. I feel like there must be a better way to do it

Comment: What does `Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date:)` do if you pass it an empty string?

Comment: @DanielT. I guess the way have it right now it will just throw an error here is my stringDateToTimestamp func
static func stringDateToTimestamp(date: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        let date = formatter.date(from: date)
        let dateStamp: TimeInterval = date!.timeIntervalSince1970
        let timestamp: String = String(dateStamp)
        return timestamp
    }

Comment: @MightAsWell It won't throw it will crash. Add a guard to make it return "" if "" is passed in. FYI creating a DateFormatter is pretty expensive so you probably shouldn't be creating a new one every time the function is called. Better to have a file private date formatter object.

Comment: @DanielT. so if I need to use that formatter through out the app it is still better to have a fileprivate func?

Comment: If you need it everywhere, don't bother making it file private. I made a new Helper for you in my answer that only makes one formatter and then reuses it for every call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with. It assumes that `Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date:)` will return an empty string if an empty string is passed into it.
I wrote an Array extension to help clean up the `if` statements.

I made the code output centric. By that I mean I looked at each output in turn and figured out all the conditions that caused it to be written to. That reduces the repeated dictionary issue you had with the code.

Lastly, in several places I just insert an empty string if no data is available, and then clean it up in a loop at the end.

My logic may not be completely correct, but the idea of just analyzing each output individually instead of all the inputs will often make code more obvious.

```
extension Array where Element == PIG_TYPES_ENUM {
    func contains(pigText: String?) -> Bool {
        guard let text = pigText else { return false }
        return self.map { $0.rawValue }.contains(text)
    }
}

func example() {
    let allPigs: [PIG_TYPES_ENUM] = [.gilt, .offDutySow, .matingSow, .drySow, .farrow]

    guard allPigs.contains(pigText: pigTypeTextField.text) else { return }
    guard (parityTextField.text ?? "") == "" else {
        pigData["parity"] = parityTextField.text!
        return
    }

    if [.gilt, .offDutySow, .matingSow].contains(pigText: pigTypeTextField.text) {
        pigData["arrivalDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: arrivalDateTextField.text ?? "")
        pigData["herdEntryDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: herdEntryDateTextField.text ?? "")
    }

    if [.offDutySow, .matingSow].contains(pigText: pigTypeTextField.text) {
        pigData["startOffDutySowDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: startOffDutySowDateTextField.text ?? "")
    }

    if [.matingSow].contains(pigText: pigTypeTextField.text) {
        pigData["semenFromBoarID"] = semenFromBoarIDTextField.text ?? ""
        pigData["technicianName"] = technicianNameTextField.text ?? ""
        pigData["matingDate"] = matingDateTextField.text ?? ""
    }

    for (key, value) in pigData {
        if value == "" {
            pigData.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote an updated Helper to work with the above as well:

```
class Helper {
    private static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()

    static func stringDateToTimestamp(date: String) -> String {
        guard date.isEmpty == false else { return "" }
        let date = formatter.date(from: date)
        let dateStamp: TimeInterval = date!.timeIntervalSince1970
        let timestamp: String = String(dateStamp)
        return timestamp
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. That was eye opening for a new way of looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

**Pass the 'pigTypeTextField.text' into the 'type' parameter**

**Swift4:**

```
func processPigType(type: String) {
  guard type == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.gilt.rawValue ||
     type == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.offDutySow.rawValue ||
     type == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.matingSow.rawValue ||
     type == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.drySow.rawValue ||
     type == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.farrow.rawValue
  else {return}

  if parityTextField.text != "" {
      pigData["parity"] = parityTextField.text!
     }

  switch type {
      case PIG_TYPES_ENUM.gilt.rawValue:
       if arrivalDateTextField.text != "" {
           self.configurePigData(pigType: .gilt)
        }

      case PIG_TYPES_ENUM.offDutySow.rawValue:
       if arrivalDateTextField.text != "" &&
         herdEntryDateTextField.text != "" &&
         startOffDutySowDateTextField.text != "" {
            self.configurePigData(pigType: .offDutySow)
        }
      case PIG_TYPES_ENUM.matingSow.rawValue:
       if arrivalDateTextField.text != "" &&
          herdEntryDateTextField.text != "" &&
          startOffDutySowDateTextField.text != "" &&
          semenFromBoarIDTextField.text != "" &&
          technicianNameTextField.text != "" &&
          matingDateTextField.text != "" {
            self.configurePigData(pigType: .matingSow)
        }

     default:
        break
    }
}

func configurePigData(pigType: PigType) {
  switch pigType {
   case .gilt:
      pigData["arrivalDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: arrivalDateTextField.text!)
      pigData["herdEntryDate"] = (herdEntryDateTextField.text != "") ? Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: herdEntryDateTextField.text!) : ""

   case .offDutySow:
      pigData["arrivalDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: arrivalDateTextField.text!)
      pigData["herdEntryDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: herdEntryDateTextField.text!)
      pigData["startOffDutySowDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: startOffDutySowDateTextField.text!)

   case .matingSow:
      pigData["arrivalDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: arrivalDateTextField.text!)
      pigData["herdEntryDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: herdEntryDateTextField.text!)
      pigData["startOffDutySowDate"] = Helper.stringDateToTimestamp(date: startOffDutySowDateTextField.text!)
      pigData["semenFromBoarID"] = semenFromBoarIDTextField.text!
      pigData["technicianName"] = technicianNameTextField.text!
      pigData["matingDate"] = matingDateTextField.text!

   default:
       break
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so that I know how to do but the repeat of assigning value to dict is what bug me but I guess there is no better way then

Answer (score -1):

1) why check if its empty after you're checking if it's has one of those values?

```
if parityTextField.text != "" {
```

2) You don't even need to check if it's one of those and then check which one... do a switch on `parityTextField.text`

```
case ""
case PIG_TYPES_ENUM.matingSow.rawValue
case PIG_TYPES_ENUM.offDutySow.rawValue
case PIG_TYPES_ENUM.gilt.rawValue
```

those are all the cases you're caring about

Comment: @shayegh well i mean all of that case need the parityTextField to be not empty and each case require checks but some of those checks are the same with a few different. So that is why im a bit confused on how to approach it. Could you please explain more?

Comment: @shayegh You should update your answer (or delete it) to reflect your mistake.